# transformers' efficiency in processing a shared prefix

Tags: huggingface-transformers

I'm using huggingface's Python module `transformers` in combination with pytorch to instantiate gpt2 and similar auto-regressive transformer models. I want to make predictions for the token that follows each of N possible strings, which all share a common prefix.  Here's a simple example with N=2:

```
s1 = "On the table I saw a red"
s2 = "On the table I saw a big"
inputs = tokenizer( [s1,s2], return_tensors="pt", padding=True)
outputs = model(**inputs)
probabilities = outputs['logits'].softmax(dim=-1)
#probabilities[i, -1, :] gives the predictive distribution for each prompt i
```

Is this efficient, or am I making the model process the tokens that make up the common prefix, "On the table I saw a", twice?  Is there a way I can force the model to share states up to the point at which the strings diverge? (Does it already do that?)